# how many ethernet cards ?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet, router

I want to use my computer as a router. So I checked how many ethernet card I have running : `lspci | grep -i net`. I got a single line ? Does it mean that I have only one "eth0" ethernet card ?

Comment: Probably. you need to look at the full output of `lspci` or `ifconfig` to find out. Note that if you have a USB card or something it won't show in `lspci`, you need `lsusb` then.

Comment: Some network cards have more than one connector (PHY) and will get listed as one PCI device, but will offer multiple links (one for each connector). Also, some ethernet cards with multiple connectors are in fact switches and have the ability to push a switch configuration to them (using `swconfig`). Then ports can be mapped to VLANs/PVIDs and the single interface connected to the system can see all VLANs using the regular 802.11q implementation. This is how for example most home routers work -- they only have a single ethernet chip with integrated switch with port-VLANs separating LAN/WAN.

Comment: @gertvdijk thank you, it is interesting - how do I check that my machine supports this feature ?

Comment: @Newben Just provide the exact hardware you have, preferrably with numeric vendor/product IDs. E.g. `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|ethernet)"`. Either way, to build a home router with scalable network interface I would recommend to buy a managed switch (or install OpenWRT on your home router for example) and use VLANs. Then use a 'trunk' port to connect all the networks with a single cable to your server. That's the most used, scalable and cheap way to do it.

Comment: @Newben How many ethernet plugs do you have?  That's usually the best way to start checking. :)

Comment: @MosheKatz I have one ethernet plug on one machine, 2 on another (plus a switch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but more than 1 line does not mean more than 1 NIC. Example

```
$ lspci | grep -i net
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716 
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5716
```

This is 1 NIC connected to eth0:0 and eth0:1 (so 2 IP adresses) that is a PCI device(!).

There is a better command:

```
$ifconfig | grep Ethernet
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:67:58:bd
eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:67:58:bd
eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:67:58:bd
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:67:58:be
eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:67:58:be
```

2 NICs both with more than 1 connection. "eth1" is a USB device though so not shown in the 1st command.

--- from comments `ip link` is even better:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether {mac} brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether {mac} brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:f
```

Comment: with one network card and 2 IP, can I use my computer as a router ?

Comment: @Newben what do you mean use it as router?

Comment: I want to connect an other ubuntu machine to mine

Comment: @Newben yes you can do that

Comment: I followed that `http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/07/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-router.html` but it supposes I have two cards. Is there some doc I can get to make this happen on my single network card machine ?

Comment: Note that the question is **how many ethernet cards**(not interfaces), `ifconfig | grep Ethernet` will show incorrect result as the sub-interfaces will end up being shown in the output..

Comment: Sticking to the first command `ifconfig | grep Ethernet | uniq -f 4` (or really anything > 1 in `uniq -f 4`) should report only the cards themselves

Comment: @Newben: that would be [a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 3):

`lspci` list alll PCI devices so if you have some old built in network card, or some usb cards it will not shown in the result, so to get more precise result try this:

```
ifconfig -a | grep Ethernet
```

Thanks for @gertvdijk note add the `-a` option to ifconfig to list all interfaces even if they are down

Comment: Darn you for being quicker.

Comment: `ifconfig` without the `-a` option will only list interfaces with their link up. Also, `ifconfig` is deprecated and one should use the `ip` toolset, e.g. `ip link` to list links.

Comment: So why downvoting?!